# Should "popperians" be capitalized?

Tags: capitalization, proper-nouns

Popperians being people who are sympathetic with Karl **Popper**'s views? In general, should groups of people who take their collective name from a proper noun in turn capitalize their name?

Comment: You should definitely capitalise *Popperians*, because the word effectively has no meaning except insofar as it references the proper noun. Things are less clear-cut with, for example, [Caesarian](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Caesarian%2Ccaesarian&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CCaesarian%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccaesarian%3B%2Cc0) because it can now have meanings that aren't directly connected to the original proper noun.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Popperian** **[usually capitalized](http://www.enacademic.com/searchall.php?SWord=Popperians&from=en&to=&submitFormSearch=Search!&stype=0)** Etymology: Karl Popper died 1994 British (Austrian born) philosopher + English an (II) : of, relating to, or characteristic of the theories of Karl Popper ; especially